# Calculating a square root

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, roots

What is the fastest way to compute the square-root of a real, positive number x to a desired number of correct digits?  For example, in number theory, $\sqrt{x}$ for nonnegative integers $x$ can be approximated to desired accuracy as a convergent of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{x}$ if this is known. In calculus,  $\sqrt{t}$ can be found using the bisection method. This method is slow. Now, $\sqrt{t}$ can be computed faster by applying Newtons' method to the polynomial $x^2-t$ for any initial guess $k$ not equal to zero. When I say "fastest" I mean "least amount of computations" :)  I also learned about Taylor polynomials; maybe using a Taylor polynomial about some $x$ close to to where $\sqrt{x}$ is known can be a fast method?

Comment: I am not that knowleadgeable in numerical analysis, but I think anything better than Newton's method will result in something a lot more difficult to implement. Newton's method is really a good method when considering difficulty versus speed. 

(Also, Newton's method proof relies on Taylor's formulas, so I guess the part on Taylor polynomials is contained in this)

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Answer (score 0):

If you want square root of $A$ then

$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n}-\frac{x^2-A}{2x},$$

by Newton Raphson successive iterations... best results with least computation.

Comment: Not necessarily. There are higher order methods that converge faster.

Comment: OP clarifies that ..When I say "fastest" I mean "least amount of computations"

Comment: You have to consider how fast the convergence is and the number of operations per iteration.